# Predictable port allocation by docker-compose scale

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The problem that I am facing is that the ports that are being mapped to the docker containers are fully random. I have the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
service1:
  restart: always
  build: ./service1/
  ports:
    - '1001-1100:1000'
  links:
    - 'postgres:postgres'
```

When starting the containers with `docker-compose up --scale service1=10` for example, I would expect the first container to use port 1001, second 1002 etc., however, every time I run it the result is undeterministic. Last time I ran it, the containers got bind to 1025-1034 and they were not in order.

Is it even possible to have an impact on the ports being used by the containers when a specific port range is specified?

Comment: What exactly you are looking here. port to map sequentially or in some pattern out of the given range ?

Comment: Sequentially would do the job fine. So container service1_1 to receive port 1001, service1_2 1002, etc. If I can predefine the pattern, it would also be a decent solution. What I want to accomplish, is, the containers to have the same ports after every start.

Comment: you have same port to your app every time you start. But scaling will trough error here as the port will be already consumed.